# Question about how to get different type of data in a line in C

Tags: c

is there anyway to use `scanf` to scan a line of things which contain different types of data for example , string and float and int IN C (c99)?

Heres my code

```
{

        float numberwithdot;
        int number;
        printf("Enter name: ");
        scanf("%d,%f",&number,&numberwithdot);
        printf("Your name is %d %f.",number,numberwithdot);
        return 0;
}
```

after i run the program and enter the value (23 2.3), it process finished with exit code 0 but out put with (2 2.000000) ,which is not good.**Anyway** , wanted to know is it possible or not using scanf to do "that"
*******New*******
Sorry i may have post a idiot sample for the question , take a look at my "failure" code

```
{
int recordnumber ,itemnumber ,quantity ;
float weight ;
char itemname[30];
char category[30];
char namelocationstat[30];

printf("Please enter 1> Record number, 2> Item name, 3> Item number, 4> Category, 5> Quantity\n""6> Weight 7> Recipient-, 8> Final Destination-, and 9> Delivery status :\n");

scanf("%d,%s,%d,%s,%d,%f,%s",&recordnumber, itemname,&itemnumber, category,&quantity,&weight, namelocationstat);

printf("%d,%s,%d,%s,%d,%.1f,%s", recordnumber, itemname, itemnumber, category, quantity, weight, namelocationstat);
```

}
i was think to use strtok to define between names and adress(havent finish the code yet) , but that off the topic , The problem i got this (1,��,0,@,0,0.0,) after inputting (1 asd 2 sad 1 1.1 asdasd asd da)

hopefully u guys can solve it , it helps alot!!

***NEW****
Problem Solved , its because of the comma i added , how folish i am !!!
Sorry for your time everyone , You guys are so awesome , sacrificing time to help ppl like me !! Wish u all have a good day ! Sir or Madam!

P.S. new "programmer" alert

Comment: Your compiler isn't warning you about your problem? If not, turn on warnings (`-Wall -Wextra` for gcc and clang)

Comment: Instead of explaining provide sample input data as part of question.

Comment: @Shawn Im using Clion and i dont see any warning about it :v

Comment: @kiran Biradar edited the post

Comment: `(23 2.3)` where is string(`name`)  in it?

Comment: What *exactly* do you type?  What *exactly* gets printed to the terminal?  What does `scanf()` actually return?  `scanf()` returns a value that tells you the number of items it successfully read.  You need to check that and make sure it's 2 in the code you've posted.

Comment: `%d,%f` contains a comma but your input does not

Comment: @kiran Birada sorry , typed the whole code wrong .Anyway , is it possible to use scanf to scan different type of data and store it (string and float and int)?

Comment: @L.Rat Yes "possible to use scanf to scan different type of data and store it" is possible.  For a specific example, you need to provide a more specific question.  True compilable code attracts up votes, Invalid " typed the whole code wrong" attracts down votes.

Comment: @Shawn Which compiler warnings do you get?

Comment: Hi L.Rat and welcome.The best present that you can do yourself is to get use to study man pages  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html   .Read this , think , what (const char *format, ...) as a parameter means , ask your self various question and then post an answer.

Comment: @L.Rat You can use `%s` to scan the string. I don't know why you want to read string since you are not inputting string.

Comment: You need to learn how to use your tools. If you're not compiling from a command line, find out where to control warnings and other options in your IDE. It'll be somewhere in the project settings, most likely.

Comment: @ chux for example , i need to store a data of a product , which includes value of product , name  and the item number **in a single line inputed by user** using printf or other funtion i dont know yet .Is that a specific example?

Comment: @Shawn yes sir/miss , will do ! thankyou!

Comment: take a look at my failure example

Comment: @L.Rat [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52650265/question-about-how-to-get-different-type-of-data-in-a-line-in-c#comment92233143_52650265) provide some more info. Is the value of the product an integer or floating point? Can the name include spaces, and what is its maximum length? Is the item number a simple integer, what range of values are possible?  I see your added code implies some things.

Comment: @chux problem solved!! sorry for your time ,,,,, Thankyou again!

Comment: @L.Rat Tip: Test the return value of `scanf()` in code to improve the speed of problem solving.

Comment: @chux WoW , theres even a thing like that ? is there a code for that ? Oe ill just google it Haha.

Answer (score 2):

> Anyway , wanted to know is it possible or not using scanf to do "that"

Yes, it is.

`scanf` continues processing the input as long as the input matches (i.e. can be turned into something matching) the format stream.

Since you match for:

```
scanf("%d,%f",&number,&numberwithdot);
         ^
        comma
```

the input must contain an integer (`%d`) followed by a comma followed by a float (`%f`).

Since your input is `23 2.3` without a comma `scanf` can only match the first integer.

Had your input been `23,2.3` with a comma, your code would have worked.

An advice: Always check the value returned by `scanf` like:

```
if (scanf("%d,%f",&number,&numberwithdot) != 2)
{
    // Error! Did not scan exactly 2 values
}
```

Comment: hello! thx for the reply , sorry for your time. i know that error , i just tyoeed it wrong on board . so sooooory about it , the real problem shows up now , plz have a look!!

Comment: @L.Rat Even after you updated your question, the problem seems the same. You scan for input where each value is separated by comma but your input does not contain comma

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to use `scanf()` to scan different type of data and store it (string and `float` and `int`)?

Yes, of course:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[21];  // Space for 20 characters + a terminating '\0'.
    float f;
    int i;  // +------------------------------ %   begins a conversion specification
    //         | +---------------------------- 20  specifies the with of the string to read
    //         | |+--------------------------- s   conversion format specifier*)
    //         | || +------------------------- f   conversion format specifier for float
    //         | || | +----------------------- i   conversion format specifier for int
    if (scanf("%20s%f%i", str, &f, &i) != 3) {  // scanf() returns the number of
                                                // arguments successfully assigned
        fputs("Input error! Expected a string containing no whitespace, a float and an integer.\n\n", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;  // return an error code
    }
    printf("\"%s\"\n%f\n%i\n", str, f, i);
}
```

*) When using `"%s"` **A L W A Y S** specify the width of the string to read: `"%[WIDTH]s"`, `"%20s"` in the example. The target (the array `str` in our example) must be at least of size width + 1.

Comment: WoW , thats too detailed !! ill crop it and set it for my desktop background for a week to reminds me that format !! thx alot sir!!

Answer (score 0):

It works just fine (just tested it). The problem is how you're imputing your numbers. Try this:

```
23,2.3
```

Furthermore, if you desire to input the way you tried, you need to change the string passed as argument to scanf:

```
scanf("(%d %f)",&number,&numberwithdot);
```